# Что такое цикл событий?

Tags: node.js, события

Что такое цикл событий (event loop) простыми словами? И почему говорят о неких витках цикла событий? Говорят, есть функция process.nextTick() в node.js для создание асихнронности, но что именно она значит и как работает?

Comment: Неплохая статья на тему: http://frontender.info/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/

Comment: Не, извините, на вторую стену текста меня сегодня уже не хватит, но суть я вам уже описал в первой же.

Comment: Все программы это по сути `while(true) ДелатьЧтоТо` - это главный цикл приложения, который и обрабатывает все события. `nextTick` прерывает выполнение текущей синхронной операции и  передает время другой, напр. огромный цикл `for` без асинхронных вызовов, пока не выполнится до конца, остановит все другие операции, если внутри не вызвать `nextTick`. Это не касается асинхронных операций - с ними все ок. Вот видео, если текст не нравится, https://youtu.be/w4EHA9xqoNw